# What is the best way to run multiple instances of Node app at the same time?

Tags: json, puppeteer

I recently made my first automated app using Node and Puppeteer. I was wondering if it was possible to run multiple instances of the app at the same time and how that would be done.

Right now, I'm simply running it one time with the Node command in the terminal. I would like to be able to run the same app multiple times to increase efficiency. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

For a "multi-threaded" Puppeteer app, consider using multiple [`BrowserContext`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v1.11.0/docs/api.md#class-browsercontext) objects, which should allow you to efficiently run Puppeteer scripts both in parallel and isolated from each others' sessions.  This allows the "parent" Node and Puppeteer processes to run in one memory footprint instead of using more memory for additional Node/Puppeteer instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster for multiple browser & parallels workers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).